# SPRING Problem Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, server

I don't usually post here, but when I post that mean that i am in deep trouble :).

So I have a .war file that I deploy with filezilla. and I work with a distant server running ubuntu. So one time, I decided to upload the war file to try new functionality after the server was not responding.

And I had an error like this : Error creating bean with name 'webSecurityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency.If you want to know more, I have uploaded the catalina.out file (no worries, I have removed everything that link to the link, so no problem of privacy) : m.uploadedit.com/beth/1586428652135.txt

Please help me StackOverflow, it's been two days and I could not resolve the problem.

Thank you in advance :).

Comment: Link is dead, 404, please post here stacktrace, what do you do before you get this error, upgrading some framework?

Comment: I reuploaded it here : http://m.uploadedit.com/beth/1586428652135.txt , thank you for your response :)

Comment: It seems to have problem with your datasource, UnknownHostException: ddns.net, try to check your hibernate configuration or see if db is up

Comment: So according to you, it's a problem of database connection ?

Comment: What I see in the log is some autowired bean failed to initialize due to an error connection to db, because an UnknownHostException, during deploy. The causes could be many, so you need to check your hibernate configuration (host, port), your connectors version, and of course db status and connectivity

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the bothering, I understand what was the error, one of the mySQL server was shutted down (404 not found). So you can close my case and if someone else have this problem, they need to check always their server. Thank you Matteo Zanini. Have a good day and week end yall :).